# How to set layer transparency QGIS C++ API 2.14?

Tags: qgis, c++, vector-layer, transparency-opacity

I want to set transparency for already loaded layer by taking it from canvas

```
QgsVectorLayer *myLayer = mpMapcanvas.layer(0);
myLayer.setLayerTransparency(50);
myLayer.triggerRepaint();
```

but get an error

> invalid conversion from ‘QgsMapLayer*’ to ‘QgsVectorLayer*'

At the same time similat code at python console works great. What I'm doing wrong? Or are there any methods to convert QgsMapLayer into QgsVectorLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to take some C++ programming classes, Python code cannot be copied 1:1.

Here's how to cast the layer:

```
QgsVectorLayer *myLayer = qobject_cast<QgsVectorLayer *>( mpMapcanvas.layer( 0 ) );
```

And while totally unrelated: if you start a new project now, better start it on QGIS 3.4 (or later).

Comment: It worked, thanks. Of course I didn't copied python code into C++ project 1:1. I'm glad to start a project on QGIS 3.4. Is there a way to install it on RHEL 7?

Comment: Best I can find is this discussion http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Compiling-QGIS-3-on-Centos-7-tt5363162.html#a5363248